# Make Magento "Continue Shopping" button redirect to the last-added-to-cart product's category

Tags: magento, continue

The continue shopping button is not working as I wish on shopping cart page.

When I click the button, then go to home page.

I want go to prev category page.

Answer (score 5):

The button as you described it is really working. Return to the home page may be one of the standard Magento behaviors.

To answer your question, here is what you can do.

**Please not that if the product is present in several categories, this will redirect to the first category it is attached to.**

These pieces of code have been successfully tested on a Magento 1.7.0.0.

PHP code would be:

```
<?php
    $lastProductAddedToCartId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastAddedProductId();
    if($lastProductAddedToCartId) {
        $productCategoryIdsArray = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($lastProductAddedToCartId)->getCategoryIds();
        $continueShoppingCategoryUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($productCategoryIdsArray[0])->getUrl();
    }
?>
```

HTML button code would be:

```
<button type="button" title="Continue Shopping" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo (isset($continueShoppingCategoryUrl)) ? $continueShoppingCategoryUrl : $this->getContinueShoppingUrl(); ?>')"><span><span>Continue Shopping</span></span></button>
```

**The codes above are, for the example, working if you put the PHP code at the beginning of the `template/checkout/cart.phtml` file which is not the best pratice.**

Best practice would be to have whether:

1) a Helper of your own that you can call in the button's `setLocation()` PHP arguments like this:

```
setLocation('<?php echo (Mage::helper('myhelper')->getContinueShoppingCategoryUrl()) ? Mage::helper('myhelper')->getContinueShoppingCategoryUrl() : $this->getContinueShoppingUrl(); ?>')
```

2) or (not so good IMO), rewrite the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart::getContinueShoppingUrl()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your detail description. But when I click "Continue shopping" button, go to the product detail page. I want go to product category page.

Comment: Please see my other answer. Just for the record: it goes to the category page only when you are redirected to the cart *right* after you added a product. If you go the cart at any other moment, Magento cannot tell which was the last added product, even more if there are several products in it. How can Magento tell which category to go to if items do not belong to the same category? Please try to add a product to the cart and click on "Continue Shopping" right after having added it. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Following comment on my first answer, I have made a more complex script which is more resource hungry as the first answer so I posted it as a separate answer. Please be careful, both are really different, on the PHP side and on the PHTML side.

Here is what I have tested successfully on a Magento CE 1.7.0.0.
The scenario below works as expected in the commented code I provide.

---

### Catalog configuration

**Category A (Furniture)**

- Product 1 (Couch)

**Category B (Electronics)**

- Product 2 (Desktop)
- Product 3 (Laptop)

---

### Scenario

a) Add Product 1 to cart => "Continue Shopping" redirects to Category A right after adding it

b) Navigate the site and go back to the cart without adding a new product => "Continue Shopping" redirects to Category A

c) Add Product 2 to cart => "Continue Shopping" redirects to Category B right after adding it

d) Navigate the site and go back to the cart without adding a new product => "Continue Shopping" redirects to Homepage as products in the cart do not belong to the same category.

e) Remove Product 1 from cart => "Continue Shopping" always redirects to Category B

f) Add Product 3 to cart => "Continue Shopping" always redirects to Category B

---

### PHP Code

```
<?php
    $continueShoppingCategoryUrl = false;

    /**
     * If we are on the cart page just after we added an item to the cart,
     * we use its category for "Continue Shopping" redirect
     */
    $lastProductAddedToCartId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastAddedProductId();
    if($lastProductAddedToCartId) {
        $productCategoryIdsArray = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($lastProductAddedToCartId)->getCategoryIds();
        $continueShoppingCategoryUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($productCategoryIdsArray[0])->getUrl();
    }

    /**
     * Otherwise, if we are on the cart page at any other moment, we make sure
     * that all items do belong to the same category and, if this is
     * the case, we use this unique category for "Continue Shopping" redirect
     * 
     * If all cart items do not belong to the same category, we are
     * compelled to let Magento process in its standard way because we 
     * cannot tell which category is the one to redirect to!
     */
    if(!$continueShoppingCategoryUrl) {
        $allCategoryIds = array();
        $cartItems = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach($cartItems as $cartItem) {
            $productCategoryIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($cartItem->getProductId())->getCategoryIds();
            $allCategoryIds = array_merge($allCategoryIds, $productCategoryIds);
        }
        $allCategoryIds = array_unique($allCategoryIds);
        if(count($allCategoryIds) === 1) {
            $continueShoppingCategoryUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(reset($allCategoryIds))->getUrl();
        }
    }
?>
```

---

### HTML button code

```
<button type="button" title="Continue Shopping" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo ($continueShoppingCategoryUrl) ? $continueShoppingCategoryUrl : $this->getContinueShoppingUrl(); ?>')"><span><span>Continue Shopping</span></span></button>
```

---

### Best practice reminder

Here again, best practice would be to have a Helper to be called on the button rather than having raw PHP code in the cart.phtml template.

Comment: I know this is a year old, but would you happen to know how to filter this by store? As you mentioned above, it goes to the first category the product is in, even if in a different store. I have tried numerous methods of filtering, but none seem to work.